# How do I let the parent container know a state change from its child component MERN

Tags: reactjs

This is the Parent Container that contains the child component ( cartitems ) and the child components contains an increment or decrement button. now when i make changes to the quantity it is updated in the child component and the database but the parent container that contains the total price of the cart items does not update

```
const Cart = () => {

 
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);

  const[Total,setTotal] = useState(0)
      const userID = useGetUserID()

      useEffect(() => {
        fetchCartitems(); 
      }, []);
      
      const fetchCartitems = async () => {
          try {
            const response = await axios.get(
              `http://localhost:5174/cart/getcart/${userID}`
            );
            setCartItems(response.data.cartItems);
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
        };
        

      useEffect(() => {
        setTotal(cartItems.reduce((total, item) => {
          return total + item.price * item.quantity;
        },0));
      }, [cartItems]);

    
console.log(Total)

  return (
    <div className='container px-10 flex'>
      <div className="">
      <h2 className='py-6'>My Cart</h2>
      <ul className='space-y-3'>
 
        {cartItems.map(item => (
          <CartItem key={item.productId} productId={item.productId} title={item.name} price={item.price} quantity={item.quantity} imgs={item.imgs}/>
        ))}
      </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="">
      {Total}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
  
}

export default Cart
```

This is the child component

```
const CartItem = (props) => {
  const [qty, setqty] = useState(props.quantity)

  

  const decreaseQuantity = async (productId, quantity) => {
    try {
     
      const response = await axios.patch("http://localhost:5174/cart/updatecart", {
        productId,
        quantity: qty - 1,
        userID: useGetUserID(),
      });
      
      if(qty > 1){
        setqty(qty => qty - 1)
        
      }
     
    console.log(response.data);
    } catch (err) {
      
      console.error(err.response.data);
    }
  }
  const increaseQuantity = async (productId, quantity) => {
    
    try {
     
      const response = await axios.patch("http://localhost:5174/cart/updatecart", {
        productId,
        quantity: qty + 1,
        userID: useGetUserID(),
      });
      
      if(qty >= 1){
        setqty(qty => qty + 1)
      }
     
    console.log(response.data);
    } catch (err) {
      
      console.error(err.response.data);
    }
  }
  

 
  return (
    <div className='flex space-x-3 font-Inter'>
      <div className="">
      <img src={props.imgs} alt="" className='w-32 h-32 rounded-md'/>
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-between">
      <h1 className='font-bold text-xl'>{props.title}</h1>
        <h1>{props.price}</h1>
       
        <div className="flex">
        <button className='border border-b-2 px-3 rounded-tl-md rounded-bl-md' onClick={() =>decreaseQuantity(props.productId,props.quantity)}>-</button>
        <h1 className='px-2'>{qty}</h1>
        <button className='border border-b-2 px-3 rounded-tr-md rounded-br-md' onClick={() =>increaseQuantity(props.productId,props.quantity)}>+</button>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
  )
}

export default CartItem
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue with the code is that the parent component `Cart` is not being re-rendered when the quantity is updated in the child component `CartItem`. This means that the `Total` state in the parent component is not being updated.

To fix this issue, you can pass a function from the parent component to the child component as a prop that will update the `cartItems` state in the parent component when the quantity is updated in the child component. This will trigger a re-render of the parent component and update the `Total` state accordingly.

Here is an example on how you can do this:

Parent Component

```
const Cart = () => {
....

const updateItemQuantity = (itemId, quantity) => {
    setCartItems(state => state[itemId].quantity = quantity);
}
.....

return (
  ....
    {cartItems.map((item) => (
            <CartItem
              key={item.productId}
              productId={item.productId}
              title={item.name}
              price={item.price}
              quantity={item.quantity}
              imgs={item.imgs}
              updateItemQuantity={updateItemQuantity} // pass the callback function as a prop
            />
      ))}
  ....
)

}
```

And then call `updateItemQuantity` when you update item quantity in the child element

```
const CartItem = () => {
   ...
   const increaseQuantity = async (productId, quantity) => {
      // update values in the database
      props.updateItemQunatity(productId, quantity);
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: May I know how do i do i trigger the re render? a sample code would be appreciated

Comment: I'm really confused i get the following Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
    at increaseQuantity

Comment: Can you share `response.data`